# How to update Hibernate if database changes

Tags: java, database, hibernate

For example, I created the hibernate.cfg.xml and generated the classes automatically (hbm.xml's).

If I realize there's something to be modified, added or deleted from the database, normally I'd have to change the database by hand and then go and change my hbm.xml's source code by hand too.

Is there a way to update without the need to remove the code and re-generate or modify code by hand?

**EDIT: What I meant is changing the data base directly and reflecting those changes in the Java code. Sorry, I wans't very clear because I didn't know there was another way around.**

Comment: take a look at http://www.liquibase.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can let Hibernate updates your database schema when you run your project by adding this line to your `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Options for auto property:

1. `create` - It creates new tables corresponding mapping or annotation. It drops existing tables and data.
2. `update` - It keeps existing data and tables. It updates schema. here we have to take care contrants.
3. `create-drop` - It is same like create but once session gets closed it drops everything.
4. `validate` - it validates or matches schema with map or annotation. It's valid for Production environment.

If you want to generate the .xml mappings from your database you can do it using reverse JDBC with Hibernate Tools. You only need to specify your database connection info.

This page have a great example on that:

[Reverse JDBC with Hibernate Tools](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/)

You can choose whatever you want, but it's much better, portable and easy to use the first option.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think OP is asking the other way round - regenerating mappings or classes from an updated database schema.

Comment: I'm not sure also... Just in case, I've updated my answer with the other option.

Comment: Not the answer I was expecting, but it's great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found the way and it's actually VERY EASY.

When we configure a "Code Generation Configuration" in Eclipse's hibernate perspective, that configuration is saved. So, when you run it again, it will create all the "hbm.xml" again from the data base.

So:

1. Make the changes you need in your database.
2. Remove the package that contains all your "hbm.xml" (Not sure if required)
3. Go to the Hibernate perspective and run your configuration again.
4. Enjoy.

I prefer this way because I don't have to edit many methods and Java logic. I can just create a few relations in my database or add some new columns. Obviously, while developing only.